# SQL Profiler on SQL Server 2005 Professional Edition

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I want to use SQL Profiler to trace the queries executed agains my database, track performance, etc. However it seems that the SQL Profiler is only available in the Enterprise edition of SQL Server 2005. Is this the case indeed, and can I do something about it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need **any** SQL license to run the client tools (Management Studio, Profiler, etc). If your organization has a copy of the installation media for Developer, Standard, or Enterprise, you can install the client tools on your local machine under the same license.

If you're working solo, I would recommend [purchasing](http://www.microsoft.com/products/info/product.aspx?view=22&pcid=f544888c-2638-48ed-9f0f-d814e8b93ca0&crumb=catpage&catid=cd1daedd-9465-4aef-a7bf-8f5cf09a4dc0#HowToBuy) SQL Developer edition, it's only $50.

Comment: I always assumed the use of the client tools required some kind of license, and I'm excited at the prospect that it doesn't! Do you have a link to a MS licensing statement that confirms this?

Comment: http://download.microsoft.com/download/1/e/6/1e68f92c-f334-4517-b610-e4dee946ef91/2008%20SQL%20Licensing%20Overview%20final.docx

Answer (score 3):

If you are open to using third party profilers, I have used [xSQL Profiler](http://www.xsqlsoftware.com/Product/xSQL_Profiler.aspx) and it performed well enough.

Answer (score 0):

The SQL Profiler tool is only available with the Standard and Enterprise version of SQL Server, however, all version can be profiled using the tool.

Source: http://www.microsoft.com/sql/prodinfo/features/compare-features.mspx

Answer (score 0):

Client tools are not licensed separately. So you can download the evaluation edition of SQL 2008 R2 and use the client tools from it (the client tools will still work even once the eval expires and the engine is no longer usable).

You must be licensed in some way for each sql server you connect to but that is not the same as requiring a license to use the tools.

You can use SQL Profiler on both Standard and Enterprise editions, but you will need certain rights to run it (you need to have sa rights or be granted ALTER TRACE permissions)